# unable to get details about a volume replicant

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I use this API to get details about a volume replicant: [API](https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/17193465.json?objectMask=mask%5Bid%2Cusername%2Cpassword%2CcapacityGb%2CsnapshotCapacityGb%2CparentVolume.snapshotSizeBytes%2CstorageType.keyName%2CserviceResource.datacenter.name%2CserviceResourceBackendIpAddress%2Ciops%2ClunId%2CactiveTransactionCount%2CactiveTransactions.transactionStatus.friendlyName%2CreplicationPartnerCount%2CreplicationPartners%5Bid%2Cusername%2CserviceResourceBackendIpAddress%2CserviceResource.datacenter.name%2CreplicationSchedule.type.keyname%5D%5D)

It fails with `500`

```
{"error":"An error has occurred while processing your request.  Please try again later.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}
```

the same mask works for a normal endurance volume, I am not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue when you try to retrieve the lunId from the replica, if you try the following mask:

```
objectMask=mask[lunId]
```

you'll get the error, however if you use the mask:

```
objectMask=lunId
```

It works :S

I'll report the issue, currenlty as workaround you can left out the lunId from your request in replicas e.g.

```
objectMask=mask[id,username,password,capacityGb,snapshotCapacityGb,parentVolume.snapshotSizeBytes,storageType.keyName,serviceResource.datacenter.name,serviceResourceBackendIpAddress,iops,activeTransactionCount,activeTransactions.transactionStatus.friendlyName,replicationPartnerCount,replicationPartners[id,username,serviceResourceBackendIpAddress,serviceResource.datacenter.name,replicationSchedule.type.keyname]]
```

Regards